# Can you create multiple variables in one line in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a lot of variables that are all the same value but they need different so they can be differentiated.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Could you do this:

```
a, b, c = []
e, f, g = 1
```

Comment: try something *first* next time ;)

Comment: It is impossible to succeed without trying.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
a = b = c = []
e = f = g = 1
```

Just they are the same objects.

But you can also do:

```
a, b, c = [[]] * 3
e, f, g = [1] * 3
```

But to not have them be the same objects:

```
a, b, c = [[] for i in range(3)]
e, f, g = [1 for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: `e, f, g = [1 for i in range(3)]` -- they are all the same objects (i.e. `e is f is g`)- most integers are cached

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yeah.

Comment: Well edit the answer then i suggest- then i'll delete my comments